# python3 12 digits script each digit equal three time beore him?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that displays **12 digits**,

each digit is equal to three times the digit before him.

I tried to code like this

```
a , b , c = 1 , 1 , 1

print(c)

while c < 12 :       # for looping

    c = c + 1        # c for counting

    b = a+b

    y = 3*b

    print(c,y)
```

can any one help me to correct the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) for that:

```
from itertools import islice

def numbers(x, base=3):
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield x * base ** n
        n += 1

for n in islice(numbers(1), 12):
    print(n)
```

Or if you really like your way of doing that, here's a fixed version of your code:

```
b, c = 1, 0
while c < 12:
    print(c, b)
    b *= 3
    c += 1
```

Comment: thank you for your support its working fine to correct my code

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a list where first element is the beginning of the multiples:

-- start with 1 or the number you like

```
multiples = [1]
for i in range(1, 12):
    multiples.append(3 * multiples[i - 1])

print(multiples)
```

-- Output : [1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147]

Comment: thank you for helping me but i didn't learn list yet its my second lesson